# Is it possible to install ubuntu 14.04 on playstation 3?

Tags: system-installation

I would like to install ubuntu 14.04 on playstation 3. Is that possible?

Comment: According to a quick googling there are some solutions out there, but not tested from me. http://www.ps3hax.net/showthread.php?t=81188 though the feature was removed by sony